# .htaccess rewrite but keep basic URL

Tags: htaccess, apache2

I have basic domain, for example, domain1.com. Also I have domain2.com which is addon domain, and I want to redirect domain2.com to domain.com?parameter=value, which is basically domain1.com, but with another template, but that **path in URL stays same**, domain2.com, not domain1.com. .htaccess file is created inside addon domain directory (public_html/domain2.com), and I have these two lines:

```
RewriteCond % ^domain2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain1.com?parameter=value [P]
```

Rewrite works, but URL in browser changes to domain1.com.

EDIT: U have this code to .htaccess, but URL change to domain1.com, instead to stay on domain2.com.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain1\.com\/\?parameter\=value" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) enabled and configured? Presumably your `RewriteCond` line is not as you have posted as otherwise it wouldn't redirect anything?

Comment: Why are you using P proxy?? This is an extremely dangerous thing to do even for highly experienced IT professionals. If your system is not configured exactly right, you will be in trouble fast- possible open proxy and/or vulnerable to other attacks. What problem are you trying to solve?? I rather suspect you are going about it the wrong way. BTW- the notion of a so-called add-on domain is extremely misleading. It may be you are following very bad advice.

Comment: @closetnoc, see edit

Comment: I updated the answer. I was not sure all of what you meant in your comment, so I thought updating the answer with more detail could be the first step to a clearer understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm mistaken, this **should** be along the lines what you're looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSyminks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-new-domain.com/$1 [NC,L]
```

If you're wanting to keep the URL the same, there's no need for a `R=302` flag, as it pushes the browser to **redirect** with a **302** code.  Essentially what you're wanting to do is just *mask* the URL to the proper location.

(Credit to @closetnoc for providing what kicked my train of thought)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your RewriteRule from your question is fundamentally incorrect:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain1\.com\/\?parameter\=value" [R=301,L]
```

My example is a typical blanket redirect that will take the request and parameters from the old domain and forward to the new domain.

In your case the `http\:\/\/domain1\.com\/\?parameter\=value` does not need to be escaped (using back-slashes) or quoted. The `^(.*)$ http://my-new-domain.com/$1` in my example will take the value from `(.*)` which would be the URI consisting of the directory path, file, and any parameters and place it at the end of a new request with your new domain using `$1`.

So any request for `www.old-domain.com/eagle-brand/products.php?type=food` will become `www.new-domain.com/eagle-brand/products.php?type=food`.

Comment: That's something like my edit up here, rewrite works fine, but URL changes from incoming domain to RewriteRule, now I am not even sure if this can work. I have even try with server alias (parked domain) in http.conf. Incoming URL must stay same, which is impossible I think with RewriteRule.